# Redis ServiceStack - Easy getting and setting of a group of values?

Tags: c#, nosql, redis, set, servicestack

I'm storing dateTime info for devices based on a unique identifier:

```
redisClient.Set("lastDateTime:ID000011112222", DateTime.Now);
```

I'm storing other info like IP Address:

```
redisClient.Set("ipAddress:ID000011112222", "0.0.0.0");
```

Now I want to get a set of the keys/values for the lastDateTime. 
I can get all of the keys:

```
var keysSet = redisClient.SearchKeys("lastDateTime:*");
```

How can I get a set (or list) of all of the keys and their values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with a Hash,
To set a value:

```
redisClient.SetEntryInHash("urn:dateTime", "ID001122", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

To get a dictionary of all ID's and values:

```
var hash = redisClient.GetAllEntriesFromHash("urn:dateTime");
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to get everything in a single call, I'd recommend you store everything in a set instead. There shouldn't be any significant performance penalty in doing so.

If you really have to store the values in many keys, then you'll have to do a KEYS command like you're doing, and then pass the output to an MGET (which is GetValues() I think for you).

Comment: Careful using `KEYS`, quoting the docs: `This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using sets.` http://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: So if I store everything in a set, what is the process for updating an individual item?  Do I have to know its index in the set?

Comment: You use the set functions (HSET, HGET, etc) to set and get values in set. Just as the main store has keys and values, a set will have its own as well. So you'll have to know individual keys if you want to manipulate those items, but you can also pull an entire set in a single call and search through it as well (assuming the set isn't huge). In your case, you could create two sets, one for storing lastdatetime and another for ipaddress.